# Download pdf files from a link

Tags: c#

i am working on .Net app that need to download research files from the given link. i checked that most of the published portal show the pdf files on pdf viewer and there to download the file, no .pdf link that can download directly. Can someone recommend how to download files in such cases. example i want to download the pdf from following link https://ietresearch.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1049/iet-epa.2019.0877 .

Comment: Using HttpClient perhaps : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=net-5.0

Answer (score 0):

As @Philip-Stuyck mentioned in the comments, you can use HttpClient to download the file. Here is the sample code:

```
using var client = new HttpClient();
var uri = new Uri("https://ietresearch.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1049/iet-epa.2019.0877");

await using var s = await client.GetStreamAsync(uri);

await using var file = File.Create("iet-epa-localcopy.pdf");
await s.CopyToAsync(file);
```

Comment: it doesn't work. it takes the html page not the pdf file